# Can i do a 301 redirect for the Googlebot Only?

Tags: seo, redirects, googlebot

Lets say a have a webpage called example.com, and a have a subdomain called sellingpage.example.com

I use sellingpage.example.com as a landing page for all my paid traffic, this is a landing page designed to explain to the users or services and to sell them our product.

Example.com is a page where the user gets a pop-up with two options "I am already a user" / "I am not a user", if he clicks in the first option he gets prompeded to login-in, if he clicks in the second option he gets redirected to the sellingpage.example.com

Will i get punished by Google if a create a 301 redirect only for the Googlebot, so when he access example.com he gets redirected to sellingpage.example.com ?

Comment: Rule 1. Never discriminate the Googlebot :::: [Canonical Links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: Rule 2. Do what Simon says. (It bares repeating!)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you are doing anything just for the Googlebot then it's a bad idea. However, I'm not sure why you feel the need to implement a redirect anyway? Providing there is a crawlable link on the page then just let Googlebot crawl naturally.

It sounds like `example.com` is thin content anyway so is unlikely to be returned in the SERPs. If this page should not be indexed then include a `noindex,follow` meta tag. You could even consider implementing a `rel="canonical"` that points to the subdomain?

Comment: We already have a canonical appointing to the subdomain, Google completely ignores it.

Comment: How are you determining that "Google completely ignores it"?